# What is the name of this rhetorical device involving the use of One. Word. Sentences. For. Effect

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, literary-techniques, rhetorical-devices

I am trying to find the name for the rather recent, I think, rhetorical device of one-word sentences used for emphasis and effect.

For example:

Columnist Ruth Marcus, writing for the [*Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/ruth-marcus-hillary-clintons-money-woes/2014/06/27/54587598-fe2f-11e3-8176-f2c941cf35f1_story.html?tid=a_inl), wrote this of Hillary Clinton's speaking fees:

> “You don’t need any more! Just. Stop. Speaking. For. Pay.”

Columnist Michael Barone, writing in the [*Washington Examiner*](http://www.washingtonexaminer.com/no-there-wont-be-a-brokered-national-convention/article/2578531), wrote this about the chances of a contested Republican convention:

> “I have bad news for those looking forward to a brokered convention. It. Isn’t. Going. To. Happen.”

Final example: Bob asks, "Are you ever going to stop using sentence fragments in your writing?"

Mary responds, "I. Don't. Think. So."

So, in the realm of rhetorical devices . . .

Repetition of a beginning word, phrase, or clause in consecutive sentences = **Anaphora**.

Insertion of conjunctions between every item in a series = **Polysyndeton**.

One. Word. Sentences. = **?  ?  ?**

Can anyone help?

---

Footnote for anyone reading. From the related question, in terms of a search for the ***origin***, really the best possibility which came to the fore was: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_guy. Possibly 1997. But the origin is still totally unclear, unfortunately; CBG could have been referring to something from the 80s, say.

Comment: Actually, they are **not** sentences!

Comment: As @trevord said they are not  sentences. They are, as you mentionnned, sentence fragments: "A SENTENCE FRAGMENT fails to be a sentence in the sense that it cannot stand by itself. It does not contain even one independent clause."  So I'd suggest "sentence fragment" for what they are and "sentence fragmentation" for the style or the process, or even "full stop fragmentation style".

Comment: Perhaps *punctuation for emphasis* as opposed to *punctuation for grammar*.

Comment: Note. Every single example of the meme you include is a **bad example**. Classically, the meme Has. Three. Words.  Three only, not four or five.

Comment: Further it **is not** a rhetorical device.  It's just an internet meme.  (Note too that it is meaningless in spoken speech, it is a written meme; like concrete poetry.)

Comment: This question is related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/name-and-origin-of-writing-with-period-after-each-word

Comment: The periods are less annoying than exclamation marks would be. Perhaps half bangs - or Cap-'n-Bang.

Comment: ***BEST! BOUNTY! EVER!***

Comment: That. Is. James. Kirk. Style.

Comment: @mary-lou Because you gave a bounty for this question,  I cannot vote to close it, even though its' a  duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/name-and-origin-of-writing-with-period-after-each-word . It's weird that people upvote that

Comment: @P.Obertelli you got it wrong, mate. The bounty offerer is Joe Blow. I edited the the original post, so you see my avatar, but twas Joe who set this up. :)

Comment: @JoeBlow right Mari-Lou , you're the one who edited the question, sorry for any confusion. Still , my comment stands. The question gets a bounty even though it's  that's a duplicate and got answered already.

Comment: @P.Obertelli if no one voted to close it as a duplicate it probably means no one had noticed that there was an older question. But I am not 100% in agreement with Mr Hen's answer; punctuating every word with a period is called *staccato*? Hmm... Staccato is the sound or musicality effect.

Comment: @jejorda noticed, he put a comment 2 hours after the question was asked. "this question is related: english.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/…"

Comment: @P.Obertelli so he should have voted to close it, but it seems he didn't. When the bounty is over you can cast your vote to close it. I'm not sure how much rep you need, I'll have a look. EDIT. You need 3,000 rep points, You're not quite there.

Comment: @P.Obertelli   Actually, if you think about it, this one is more current. it comments on a phenomenon that probably didn't exist in journalism six or seven years ago. The examples, as Joe Blow pointed out, are not related to memes. They do not consist of the magical formula of three, so the context is fairly different.

Comment: what do you mean by James Kirk style?  @dangph

Comment: @JoeBlow, if you watch the original Star Trek from the 1960s, that is how the character Captain James T. Kirk spoke.

Answer (score 5):

When every single word **in a short phrase** is punctuated by a period (full stop *BrEng*), what effect does this produce in the reader? He or she is forced to pause before moving onto the next word. So, yes, I would call this form of writing, *and speaking* a *[rhetorical device](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rhetorical%20device)*, because it creates an effect on the audience.

This (for want of a better expression) “period emphasis” is similar to how we might place a word, or short phrase in  *italics*, **bold**, “[scare quotes](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/scare)”, or in block capital letters, i.e. CAPS. Ultimately, in the quotations cited by the OP, the journalist's aim is to grab the reader's attention.

Punctuating a short phrase in this manner is an economical way of adding pathos, levity, and/or tension to any news or piece of communication. A way to highlight a moment of mock drama; e.g. [Janice Litman](https://youtu.be/1QnQ3MWp6tI?t=1m14s) from F.R.I.E.N.D.S  and her catchphrase Oh. My. God!; extreme levity (Best. Party. Ever.) or even a powerful way to emit a threat (You. Will. Die).

**What's it called?**

*All The Tropes* has a page dedicated to [**Punctuated! For! Emphasis!**](https://allthetropes.org/wiki/Punctuated!_For!_Emphasis!#Live.21_Action.21_MOVIES.21) and provides these examples from the Harry Potter series among many others from different movies and books

> "Life. Isn't. Fair."
>   "Don't. Lie. To me."
>   "You. Don't. Know."
>   "Don't. Call. Me. A. Coward!"
>   "Mr. Potter... Our. New. Celebrity."

Comment: Though I hesitate to call TV Tropes a reliable source, I think Punctuated For Emphasis is a pretty accurate description.

Comment: Good answer. Know Your Meme has further information about the trope, in an entry titled "[Best. Day. Ever.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/best-day-ever)" The suggestion there is that the punctuated form began as an attempt to represent phrases (such as "Best day ever") that were spoken with long pauses between each word. Know Your Meme traces the usage at least as far back as December 1, 2008. I'm not sure, though, whether KYM's naming the meme after the (supposedly) first published instance of the phrase in which it appeared counts as naming the rhetorical device itself.

Comment: heh, "Punctuated! For! Emphasis!" clever and apposite.

Comment: It's interesting that we're no closer at all to getting any sort of early usage.  Sven, that article is pretty low quality, at least it mentions the usage in Tim Kring's "Heroes" in 2008. (It's really inconceivable that was the first usage/invention .. that was just one of any number of throw-away uses of it when it was particularly popular.)

Comment: With careful consideration and the bounty expiring I've decided this is the Best answer - *"Punctuated! For! Emphasis!"* is the closest thing to a "name of the meme".  By all means, the academic answer below is superb and fully examines language describing that type of rhetorical device (t's so academic and excellent, it don't need no steenking bounty!)  MLA has saved the day.

Comment: @JoeBlow you should post your theory / ideas /answer on the older question. and I don't think anyone has pointed out the magic formula of three words. That is definitely a meme, and something which you said in an earlier post which you've recently deleted.  But the OP in *this* question is not asking about a meme, and the examples cited by the OP are not snappy one liners.

Comment: “Just. Stop. Speaking. For. Pay.” ... michael barone (epitome of cheap commercial meme-writing)  "It. Isn’t. Going. To. Happen." ... etc. The question was asked: this answer gives the answer.   I TOTALLY understand what you mean and had exactly those thoughts.  But in the end, I'm right. This answer gets the bounty this time!!!   Awesome!   and again THANKS for "Punctuated! For! Emphasis!" it's the only real answer to this question floating around

Comment: Look at it this way. In the only actual examples given in the OP, *“Just. Stop. Speaking. For. Pay.”* and *"It. Isn’t. Going. To. Happen."* they are the epitome of the meme, and you'd label it *exactly*  "Punctuated! For! Emphasis!".  Not onomatonic scesis.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot--a *lot*--of terms used in rhetoric to describe the event of single-word sentences and/or juxtaposition of short sentences without explicit conjunctions. The most basic term for this is **parataxis** or **asyndeton**. An even broader heading would be **ellipsis**. There are probably 25 to 50 synonyms and related terms. However, all of these fall short of being a name for exactly the phenomenon you are talking about.

So does this--although, if I had to write about the phenomenon you are talking about, I would be quick to bring it in:

**Scesis Onomaton** (ske’-sis-o-no’-ma-ton):

> 1. A sentence constructed only of nouns and adjectives (typically in a regular pattern).
> 2. A series of successive, synonymous expressions.
>
> Examples:  "Political problem. Violent solution. Civil war.
> Revolution. Riots. Fire. Bullets. Death. Broken nation. Torn apart.
> Broken promises. Broken hearts."
>
> "Don’t forget to write! Remember me in letters! I hope to hear from
> you soon!"

([source](https://dailytrope.com/category/scesis-onomaton/))

There are also **brachylogia**--

> The absence of conjunctions between single words. Compare asyndeton.
> The effect of brachylogia is a broken, hurried delivery.
> Examples:
>
> "Phillip! Rise! Eat! Leave!"
>
> "Love, hate, jealousy, frenzy, fury drew
> him from pity" —Angel Day

([source](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/B/brachylogia.htm))

--and **isocolon**

> A series of similarly structured elements having the same length. A
> kind of parallelism.
> Examples
> Veni, vidi, vici (I came, I saw, I conquered)

([source](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/I/isocolon.htm)).

The term [articulus](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/articulus.htm) captures a bit of the sense of dilation intended by the use of periods in your phenomenon.

Please note that this question is a dupe of at least two others on English.Stackexchange (don't have the links anymore, sorry)--none of which has, in my opinion, a definitive answer. That's not to say a term for exactly this rhetorical gesture doesn't exist. (If it doesn't, it will in a couple years.) But the best I can do for now is find something similar.

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes, seven different terms is definitely an answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it's *the* answer  :)  Indeed I was just about to say: The problem is this is an academic answer to, err, "what do you call this modality".  It does not at all address the issue "what's this meme called?"  You know?